# Expand two large data files and apply using data.table?

Tags: r, memory, data.table

I am attempting to apply a function to two data sets `df1` and `df2` where `df1` contains `(a, b)` and can be 1 million rows long, and `df2` contains `(x, y, z)` and can be very large, anywhere from ~100 to >10,000.  I would like to apply a function `foo` over every combination of both data sets and then sum over the second data set.

```
foo <- function(a, b, x, y, z) a + b + x + y + z
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 11:20)
df2 <- data.frame(x= 1:5, y = 21:25, z = 31:35)
```

The code I am using to apply this function (taken from @jlhoward here [How to avoid multiple loops with multiple variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572050/how-to-avoid-multiple-loops-with-multiple-variables-in-r))

```
foo.new <- function(p1, p2) {
  p1 = as.list(p1); p2 = as.list(p2)
  foo(p1$a, p1$b, p2$x, p2$y, p2$z)
}

indx   <- expand.grid(indx2 = seq(nrow(df2)), indx1 = seq(nrow(df1)))
result <- with(indx, foo.new(df1[indx1, ], df2[indx2, ]))
sums   <- aggregate(result, by = list(rep(seq(nrow(df1)), each = nrow(df2))), sum)
```

However, as `df2` gets large (>1000) I quickly run out of memory to perform the `result` function above (running 64bit PC with 32GB RAM).

I have read about `data.table` quite a bit but can't evaluate whether there is a function in there that would assist in saving memory.  Something that would replace `with` and create a smaller file at the `result` step, or `expand.grid` at the `index` step, which creates the largest file by far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a data.table solution: should be pretty fast:

```
library(data.table)
indx<-CJ(indx1=seq(nrow(df2)),indx2=seq(nrow(df1))) #CJ is data.table function for expand.grid
 indx[,`:=`(result=foo.new(df1[indx1, ], df2[indx2, ]),Group.1=rep(seq(nrow(df1)), each = nrow(df2)))][,.(sums=sum(result)),by=Group.1]

    Group.1 sums
 1:       1  355
 2:       2  365
 3:       3  375
 4:       4  385
 5:       5  395
 6:       6  405
 7:       7  415
 8:       8  425
 9:       9  435
10:      10  445
```

Comment: I think this works well so thanks very much.  However, to replicate the results I had to change the `indx` to `indx<-CJ(indx1=seq(nrow(df1)), indx2=seq(nrow(df2)))`.  Don't know if that is correct or if I am doing something else wrong in the process.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you.Regarding `CJ`, please look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948686/why-is-expand-grid-faster-than-data-table-s-cj

Comment: @Legalizeit: I haven't tested the code in real data. `CJ` is 90 % faster than `expand.grid` as documented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948686/why-is-expand-grid-faster-than-data-table-s-cj) and grouping is faster in data.table, and I think because of these, it should save a lot of time.

Comment: yea this is really fast, I was just trying it out with 1e6 rows for the first and 100 for the second.  But, the size of `indx` is about the same as when done with `expand.grid` which isn't surprising because it doesn't create it lazily.  I would like to know if there is a way to do this like in python with itertools, where the combinations are created as an iterator so there is no memory footprint