# There is a way in R of using expand.grid in a multicore setting?

Tags: r, time, multicore

I would like to speed up `expand.grid` for the use case below:

```
comb <- expand.grid(1:7, 1:7, 1:7, 1:7, 1:7, 1:7, 1:7, 1:7, 1:7)
```

Q1. Is it possible to create a multicore version of `expand.grid` with an option to specify the number of used cores?

Q2. Is it possible to estimate the heap size given a specific computation?

Q3. Is it possible to estimate beforehand the required compute time?

Comment: takes just a couple seconds on my machine, is that too slow?

Comment: In this case the length of comb is of 40353607... 40353607 rows in a couple of seconds?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254476/combinatorial-iterator-like-expand-grid