# Faster way to achieve filtering for all possible combinations

Tags: r, combinations

Consider I have a data frame like this,

```
set.seed(1)

q<-100

df <- data.frame(Var1 = round(runif(q,1,50)),
                    Var2 = round(runif(q,1,50)),
                        Var3 = round(runif(q,1,50)),
                            Var4 = round(runif(q,1,50)))
attach(df)
```

As you realized, `q` is standing for setting the length of the each columns in the dataframe.

I want to make a filtering of all possible combinations of the columns. It can be anything. Let's say I am seeking for if the devision of the sums of the first two columns and the sums of the last two columns greater than 1 or not.

One thing to achieve that, using `expand.grid()` function.

```
a <- Sys.time()

expanded <- expand.grid(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4)

Sys.time() - a

Time difference of 8.31997 secs


expanded  <- expanded[rowSums(expanded[,1:2])/ rowSums(expanded[,3:4])>1,]
```

However it takes a lot time! To make it faster, I tried to follow the answer with `rep.int()` function in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405637/use-outer-instead-of-expand-grid/10406005#10406005) question and designed my own function.

```
myexpand <- function(...) {

 sapply(list(...),function(y) rep.int(y, prod(lengths(list(...)))/length(y)))

}
```

But it is not so promising again. It takes more time comparing to my expectation and the `expand.grid` also.And,  If I set a greater `q`, it becomes a nigthmare!

Is there a proper way to achieve this a lot faster (1-2 seconds) with maybe matrix operations before applying `expand.grid` or `myexpand` . And, I wonder if it is a weakness  of using an interpreted language like R... Software suggestions are also acceptable.

Comment: Maybe try parallelization...? or maybe an `Rcpp` implementation?

Comment: @Sotos I have no idea about parallelization and how to apply it in R. But I will have a look at.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31254476/5635580) to get you started

Comment: you might want to check out https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppAlgos/index.html

Answer (score 3):

For this particular condition (i.e. ratio of sums > 1), you might want to consider using the `data.table` package:

```
system.time({
    #generate permutations of Var1 & Var2 and Var3 & Var4
    DT12 <- DT[, CJ(Var1=Var1, Var2=Var2, unique=TRUE)][, s12 := Var1 + Var2]
    DT34 <- DT[, CJ(Var3=Var3, Var4=Var4, unique=TRUE)][, s34 := Var3 + Var4]

    #perform a non-equi join
    DT12[DT34, on=.(s12>s34), allow.cartesian=TRUE,
        .(Var1=x.Var1, Var2=x.Var2, Var3=i.Var3, Var4=i.Var4)][, s12:=NULL]
})
```

timing:

```
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.06    0.08
```

output:

```
         Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
      1:    2    5    2    4
      2:    4    3    2    4
      3:    5    2    2    4
      4:    2    6    2    4
      5:    4    4    2    4
     ---                    
1753416:   50   49   49   48
1753417:   50   50   49   48
1753418:   50   49   49   49
1753419:   50   50   49   49
1753420:   50   50   49   50
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
q <- 100
DT <- data.table(Var1 = round(runif(q,1,50)),
    Var2 = round(runif(q,1,50)),
    Var3 = round(runif(q,1,50)),
    Var4 = round(runif(q,1,50)))
```

---

edit: For summing of positive numbers, you can prob use the following (caveat: it will not be faster than using a Rcpp approach).

```
system.time({
    S <- DT[, .(UB=90 - Var1, C1=Var1)]
    for (k in 2:4) {
        S <- DT[S, on=paste0("Var", k, "<UB"), allow.cartesian=TRUE,
            mget(c(names(S), paste0("x.Var", k)))]
        setnames(S, paste0("x.Var", k), paste0("C", k))
        S[, UB := UB - get(paste0("C",k))]
    }
    S[, UB := NULL][rowSums(S)>30L]
})
```

timing:

```
   user  system elapsed 
   3.48    4.06    3.51
```

output, `S`:

```
> S
          C1 C2 C3 C4
       1: 14 33 14  6
       2: 14 33 14 25
       3: 14 33 14 24
       4: 14 33 14 19
       5: 14 33 14 10
      ---            
34914725: 31 39  3  8
34914726: 31 39  3  8
34914727: 31 39  3  9
34914728: 31 39  3 16
34914729: 31 39  3  8
```

Comment: I got the error `object 'x.Var1' not found`. Additionally,  if I run `nrow(expanded)` after filtering by `>1` or not, I get **55615910** but you found **1753420**.And one thing more, the dataframe example is just a fake data created for make the question replicable.In reality, `expand.grid` function also works with different number of inputs. I.e.  `expand.grid(1:100,1:5,1:1000)` .  I don't really know if datatable is fine with list type inputs...

Comment: i am guessing that your solution has duplicates. `data.table::CJ` can take in any number of vectors as well

Comment: I don't understand but I still get `object 'x.Var1' not found` error. And one more thing just to make it easier, what if we make the filtering say total sum of all variables greater than 30 and less than 90. If I apply this, `DTnew <- DT[, CJ(Var1,Var2,Var3, Var4, unique=FALSE)][, Total := Var1+ Var2 +Var3 + Var4]` . It takes more time comparing to `expand.grid`. Sorry I am not so familiar with DT.

Comment: I will take a look at the error later. For sum, you can use Joseph Wood’s RcppAlgos package

Comment: I talked to Joseph Wood on this site under a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569176/r-permutations-and-combinations-with-without-replacement-and-for-distinct-non-d/47983855?noredirect=1#comment101424480_47983855) he answered. And he said he was sorry about the Cartesian Product.Unfortunately `RcppAlgos` package does not have an option for it but it is something that he is working on...He also saw this question as he said. By the way, thank you for your help and sorry for the delay of the answer.

Comment: @maydin i am not getting the error. Did you use your own data.frame or my data.table data? if u are using the former, can you set it to data.table using `setDT(df)`

Comment: Sorry but I still get. And I used your DT input. It is happening `DT12[DT34, on=.(s12>s34), allow.cartesian=TRUE,
        .(Var1=x.Var1, Var2=x.Var2, Var3=i.Var3, Var4=i.Var4), by=.EACHI][, s12:=NULL]` part.Anyway, I will upvote your answer..

Comment: can you share your data.table version?

Comment: `packageVersion("data.table")` gives  `1.12.2`

Comment: so if u run the data code in a new R session and then the top code panel, you get the `object 'x.Var1' not found`?

Comment: woah thanks. learned about streamable.com today. let me chew over it some more. maybe there might be some seed that can trigger the error. can you print DT12 and DT34? i added something to specify the names explictly. strange error

Comment: @chinsoon12 why the ```.EACHI```? Since there is no aggregation, there's probably no memory saving using it, right...?

Comment: @Cole, thanks for that. Yeah not required. Not in front of computer to test though

Answer (score 0):

How about using `tidyr` and `dplyr`?

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

expanded <- 
  df %>% 
  expand(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4)
  mutate(res = (Var1 + Var2)/(Var3 + Var4)) %>%
  filter(res > 1)
```

Note that expand works slightly differently from expand.grid - it only keeps the unique rows - so this may not be what you need.

On my computer, this all takes less than a second.

Comment: How did you calculate `expanded` ? It is the real problematic part.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I thought it was just the calculation and filtering step that you wanted to speed up.  I've now edited my response to include the expansion step.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I am really appreciated. However, this problem is not about using `base R` versus `dplyr`. It is much more complicated. And using pipe operator is not a solution. Because I am seeking for possible matrix operations before expanding which result in a **real fast** solution. Once you run the codes on your computer, you can realize the situation.  If you follow my question step by step, and read the commands like  parallelization suggestion, you will understand the real topic.  If the `%>%` were the case, believe me, I could handle it without asking. Thank you very much.